# Website responsive problem in facetwp template

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, responsive

What is the correct way to make the template that the facetwp plugin provides me responsive since as it is a shotcode it is giving me problems.

The page is https://f3mkt.com/marel/catalogo/

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

With @media css provided in their database of gists [here](https://gist.facetwp.com/?_keywords=responsive)
you can use it as a base

```
.fwp-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .fwp-grid {
    display: block;
  }
}

.fwp-grid .fwp-grid-col {
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .fwp-grid .fwp-grid-col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .fwp-grid .fwp-grid-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.fwp-grid .fwp-grid-col h3 {
  padding-top: .25em;
}

.fwp-grid img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```